# Implementing single signon using LDAP in an MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, single-sign-on

Using MVC3, EF 4.1

I need to validate the username against LDAP and stored his user info in object that would persist throughout his visit (timeout is not concern). I need this object to check if belongs to a group?

Example properties to enable access:
isNextGenMonitor, isNextGensupervisor, isNextGenLead and isNextGenadmin

Also Include user info:
firstname, lastname, department, email

Can anyone post a link or example of creating to User object that will presist with his list of groups and user info?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to realize Single Sign On is by using Kerberos (SPNEGO) and not LDAP. The framework will provide you the `SecurityPrincipal` obtained by IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I see no persistence "by using Kerberos (SPNEGO)".

For SSO look at SAML or Liberty frameworks.

It is not clear why you need another object for persistence beyond LDAP.
-jim

Comment: Persistence has nothing to do with the authentication. Additional user information is always stored in the session.